# Refresh a div and avoid refreshing a span/div within refreshing div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div refreshing which is working but is it possible to avoid refreshing a `DIV / SPAN` within the refreshing div?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      readings();
    });

    function readings(){
        $('#readingss').load('test_update.php', function(){
           setTimeout(readings, 1000);
        });
    }
</script> 

<div id="readingss">
<span>I dont want this span to be refreshed</span>

<?php include('test_update.php'); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: You're replacing the whole tag. Why not move the `span` outside the `div`?

Comment: There is no way you can escape the span refresh since it is inside the `readingss` div. 

Possible solution would be move the span out of the div. No there way around.

Comment: I think this is asking like how to show a child element when the parent is hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use additional wrapper

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      readings();
    });

    function readings(){
        $('#test_update_wrapper').load('test_update.php', function(){
           setTimeout(readings, 1000);
        });
    }
</script>

<div id="readingss">
    <span>I dont want this span to be refreshed</span>
    <div id="test_update_wrapper">
        <?php include('test_update.php'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```